# Searching relations between values in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, search, key

I'm trying to search relations between values contained in several keys from a dictionary, like this:

```
dictionary = {'103': ['26', '69', '91', '47', '19', '53'], '022': ['19', '92', '57', '48', '36', '46'], '507': ['47', '13', '91', '24', '74', '27'], '061': ['06', '27', '26', '71', '86', '46'], '875': ['25', '16', '28', '62', '80', '21']}
[value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value in key.lower()]
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

And I don't get to know why! Can anyone help me?

Comment: What *relations*? What is the desired behavior?

Comment: `value` is a list. Maybe you mean to scan the items, in that case, you need to loop on `value` as well.

Comment: please provide what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can't test for the containment of a list in a string. For strings, the left hand side of the `in` operator should also be a string.

If you need to find values that contain any string which is contained in the key, you can use `any`:

```
lst = [value for key, value in dictionary.items() if any(v in key for v in value)]
print(lst)
# [['06', '27', '26', '71', '86', '46']]
```

If you need to find the contained string itself, you can loop on the dictionary values and test each string on the key:

```
lst = [v for key, value in dictionary.items() for v in value if v in key]
print(lst)
# ['06']
```

Comment: This might be the correct answer as I understand the question. But this would return an empty list (so is this really what he wants?)